# Windows Local File Sytem Access APIs

Tags: c#, c, windows, data-access, apimonitor

I'm building some kind of scan algorithm for audio files.
I am using multiple threads that are processing their assigned segments of the file. The performance is quite good, but if I compare it with the Microsoft Media Foundation Transcode APIs it is still much slower. So I've removed the processing of audio frames so it is only the IO-access left. But it is still much slower than MediaFoundation. So I was wondering how it is possible that just reading out the whole file using a FileStream is slower than processing the whole file using MediaFoundation. I've a had a look at the processing using the [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) but the result is quite strange:

I can't see any file system access in the API Monitor(I've turned on all Data Access APIs in the monitor):

[image]

So are there any faster APIs, a developer can't use? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point your attention on Multimedia Class Scheduler Service (MMCSS) of Windows - [MMCSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684247(v=vs.85).aspx). MediaFoundation is media framework which is optimized for processing of media content. As a result it could process reading - writing with the specific optimized mode. MMCSS has the next names - modes:
Audio,
Capture,
Distribution,
Games,
Playback,
Pro Audio,
Window Manager

MediaFoundation creates WorkQueue via MFAllocateWorkQueue and executes task via 
[MFBeginRegisterWorkQueueWithMMCSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701600(v=vs.85).aspx)